# Java - Writing TO standard in?

Tags: java, swing, stdin

I have an application in which it would be very convenient for me to have a mouse click event emulate a user typing in a certain string to standard input. So I was wondering, is there a way in code to WRITE to standard in? I realize it's a bit of a hack, but it would work very well for what I need to do.

EDIT (in response to Hovercraft's EDIT2):

Thanks. I understand how that code keeps the human player from moving a piece when they shouldn't. What I don't understand is how you are envisioning the main game loop. Would you mind writing code to show me what you're thinking for that? Are you just picturing a busy-wait loop that constantly generates new computer moves and calls your `Move()` method (most of the time being rejected while it's waiting for the human player to make a move)? Something like this?

```
public void gameLoop()
{
   while (gameNotOver)
   {
      Move compMove = generateComputersNextMove();
      move(blackPlayer, compMove); // where the blackPlayer is the computerPlayer 
   }
}
```

Comment: Where does the text ultimately need to go? Maybe if you describe your problem we can help you come up with a reasonable solution. It just doesn't make sense to *write* to standard-in from inside the process.

Comment: Did you try the `Robot`?

Comment: @JeremyHeiler - Basically, I want my code to block at a certain point and wait for the user to click a specific JLabel in my JFrame. Once the user clicks a JLabel, I want the code to resume, after getting the id of the JLabel that was clicked. I'm not sure how I would go about doing this. The way I had it before was that at that point in the code, the user would just type in an id (and Scanner's next() method blocks for you).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You state:

> Basically, I want my code to block at a certain point and wait for the user to click a specific JLabel in my JFrame. Once the user clicks a JLabel, I want the code to resume, after getting the id of the JLabel that was clicked. I'm not sure how I would go about doing this. The way I had it before was that at that point in the code, the user would just type in an id (and Scanner's next() method blocks for you).

You don't want to block your program (not in an event-driven program) so much as change the state of your GUI, and base your response to user's input on this state. Your attempted solution is a *linear* way of thinking, and doesn't work well with Swing or other event driven GUI's.

For instance as a simple example consider giving your program a boolean variable,

```
private boolean labelClicked = false;
```

And change this to true in the JLabel's MouseListener after the JLabel has been clicked. Then only respond to other user input if the boolean is true.

Or another possible solution: if you want to activate a JButton after a JLabel has been pressed, then make the JButton disabled, and call setEnabled(true) on the JButton from within the JLabel's MouseListener.

The key is to think *Event-Driven Programming*.
The other key when asking questions like this in this forum is not to ask us a code-specific question, but rather a behavior-specific question. The true question here is not how to write to the standard in, but rather how to get your program to pause and await user input -- that's a big difference.

Finally, if you need more specific and better recommendations, please fill us in on the details of your problem, and certainly ask questions if any of this is confusing. Best of luck!

**Edit 1**
You're likely going to have several classes including GUI and non-GUI classes managing this application, and the non-GUI classes can include:

- Player class: this can be either human or computer
- Board class: the logical (non-gui) representation of the chess board
- Piece class: abstract class that all the concrete Pieces derive from
- ChessAI class: this is your AI class, the one that figures out for the computer what the next best move should be.
- Game class: perhaps the most important class for this discussion as this will control game flow and decide whose turn it is to move.

The Game class will have fields including a Player field called `turn` that will hold a reference to whoever's turn it is. So say your Game class holds two Player variables, humanPlayer and computerPlayer. The turn variable will hold one or the other of these objects, and how Player responds will depend on what object is held by turn.

The Game class will have a loop of sorts, a game loop, that alternates between telling the humanPlayer object and the computerPlayer object that its their turn to move.

So say its the computer's turn, and it is taking a while to calculate the next best move. If meanwhile the human player tries to drag a chess piece on the GUI, the GUI will inform the Game class of the human's attempt to move, the Game class will check if it's the human's turn (by checking `if (turn == humanPlayer)`) and if it's not the human's turn, Game will inform the GUI this, and the GUI will set the piece back to where it was and perhaps pop up a warning message.

After the computer has requested Game to move its piece, Game will tell the GUI to move the computer's piece, and then Game will set turn = humanPlayer, now allowing the human player to move. After humanPlayer tries to move, the GUI will tell Game of the human's attempted move. Game will check if its a valid move, and if so, will tell computerPlayer that it should now make a move.

Note that when I say "tell", I mean that it will call a public method on that object.

**Edit 2**
I mean something sort of like this:

```
public class Game {
   private Player whitePlayer;
   private Player blackPlayer;
   private Player turn;
   private Board board = new Board(); // non-GUI logical board
   private Gui gui; // the Swing GUI that displays all

   public Game(String humanPlayerName, boolean humanWhite) {
      if (humanWhite) {
         whitePlayer = new HumanPlayer(humanPlayerName, this);
         blackPlayer = new ComputerPlayer("Computer", this);
      } else {
         whitePlayer = new ComputerPlayer("Computer", this);
         blackPlayer = new HumanPlayer(humanPlayerName, this);
      }
   }

   public void start() {
      whitePlayer.setMyTurn(true); // tell white player to move
   }

   public void move(Player playerMakingMove, Move move) {

      // only respond if the right player is making the move
      if (turn == playerMakingMove) {
         // check if its a valid move
         // if so, tell GUI to make move
         // check if game over

         turn.setMyTurn(false); // current player's turn is over
         turn = (turn == blackPlayer) ? whitePlayer : blackPlayer; // swap players
         turn.setMyTurn(true); // tell other player, it's his turn

         turn.makeMove(); // *** added
      } else {
         // send message that it's not their turn to move
      }
   }
}
```

So if the human player tries to move the GUI will move(...) for the human player, but the Game object won't respond unless it is in fact the human's turn.

**Edit 3**
`makeMove()` method added to Player
Note that the Game's `move(...)` method may be all the game loop that is needed, especially if the ComputerPlayer's `makeMove(...)` method tells the AI engine to create the next best move and then calls Game's move(...) method again:

```
abstract class Player {
   private String name;
   private boolean myTurn = false;
   protected Game game;

   public Player(String name, Game game) {
      this.name = name;
      this.game = game;
   }

   public abstract void makeMove();

   public boolean isMyTurn() {
      return myTurn;
   }

   public void setMyTurn(boolean myTurn) {
      this.myTurn = myTurn;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

}

class HumanPlayer extends Player {

   public HumanPlayer(String name, Game game) {
      super(name, game);
   }

   @Override
   public void makeMove() {
      // TODO: ask GUI to inform player that it's his turn to move and accept the move

   }


}

class ComputerPlayer extends Player {
   private ChessAi chessAi = new ChessAi();

   public ComputerPlayer(String name, Game game) {
      super(name, game);
   }

   @Override
   public void makeMove() {
      game.move(this, chessAi.calcBestMove());
   }

}
```

Both players would call `game.move(...)` when they have figured out the move, which makes the Game prompt the next player to move.... until game is over.

Note, that this is not a running program and not meant to be, but more of a mock-up to illustrate possible game logic. I've not done something like this, and there are probably better and cleaner ways to do this, but I just want to get the point across of ways of implementing turn-based logic in an event-driven GUI program.

**Edit 4**
Compile and run the following simple event driven GUI:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class EventDrivenGui extends JPanel {
   private static final Color GO_COLOR = Color.green;
   private static final Color STOP_COLOR = Color.red;
   private static final int SIDE = 300;
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 4 * 1000; // change light every 4 seconds
   private boolean go = false;
   private JButton button = new JButton("Button");


   public EventDrivenGui() {
      add(button);
      button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
      new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()).start();
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

      Color color = go ? GO_COLOR : STOP_COLOR;
      g2.setColor(color);
      g2.fillOval(0, SIDE / 3, SIDE, SIDE);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(SIDE, (4 * SIDE) / 3);
   }

   private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         if (go) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(EventDrivenGui.this, "Button is Active");
         }
      }
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         // toggle go. if true, now false, and visa versa
         go = !go;
         repaint(); // redraw oval
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            EventDrivenGui mainPanel = new EventDrivenGui();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("EventDrivenGui");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }

}
```

You'll see that there's a JButton held in a JPanel. You as the user can press the button any time you'd like, but it will only respond when the light is green (when the go boolean variable is true). This is one example where the button's behavior, whether it responds to presses or not, depends on the state of the class, whether go is true or not. Once the GUI is set up -- the constructor has been called, it has been placed in a JFrame, and is displayed, there's no code that blocks or anything like that. There's a Swing Timer whose only job is to toggle go's value and repaint the JFrame, but that's it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I still don't understand how to do what I need to do. I need to have my program wait for the user to press something. How can that possibly happen without it blocking at some point? If I don't block, code will always have to be executing, no? What code should be executing while I'm waiting for the user to click something?

Comment: @Tim: You're still in the mind-set of creating a linear non-event driven console program, and again, this just won't work with event-driven GUI's. The code that is running when you are waiting is some behind-the-scenes event loop created and maintained by the Swing library, that you never see or really care about. The key is that the user is free to press any button that he wants to, but how your program reacts to it will depend on how you've written your code. For a more detailed explanation, you should tell us and show us more about your program.

Comment: I wrote an ai chess game that users can play against. Right now, it's just a textual interface and in order to move a piece, the user must specify the location of it on standard in, and then the location to move it to (this is where it blocks, waiting for user input when it's the user's turn). All I want to do now is change it so the user specifies the movement of a piece by clicking on a piece on a gui (that I've already made), and then clicking on the square to move it to. I'm still lost when you say "The code that is running when you are waiting is some behind-the-scenes event loop"

Comment: @Tim: please see **Edit 1** above.

Comment: Thanks for sticking around. I'm with you in your Edit 1 all the up until this point: "After the computer has requested Game to move its piece, Game will tell the GUI to move the computer's piece, and then Game will set turn = humanPlayer, now allowing the human player to move. After humanPlayer tries to move, the GUI will tell Game of the human's attempted move. Game will check if its a valid move, and if so, will tell computerPlayer that it should now make a move." Since, as you mentioned, there is a main game loop, how will the loop stop and wait for the user's input? HOW? without blocking?

Comment: @Tim: please see **Edit 2** above.

Comment: Please see my EDIT in the my main question.

Comment: Interesting. But my concern is still what would happen in this little block of code that you left to-do later: "public void makeMove() {
      // TODO: ask GUI to inform player that it's his turn to move and accept the move " So my question remains: how do you accept the move in this block of code without blocking? If you get to makeMove(), you either block and wait for the user's response, or you just execute some code and return. There are no other options as far as I can tell. Do you see what I'm saying?

Comment: @Tim: the Gui could have a boolean that this model will set telling it when it will allow moves and when it won't. If it will allow moves, when the user makes a move, the Gui will notify the model. When the boolean is set so that it won't allow a move, the Gui will move the piece back to its original position.

Comment: But what is the main thread of execution DOING while it's the user's turn? What code is it executing? Unless it blocks while the it's the user's turn, it must executing some lines of code.

Comment: @Tim: it's doing nothing and it's blocking nothing. If you create a Swing GUI with a JButton in the middle of it, what is the code doing while waiting for the user to press the button?

Comment: "it's doing nothing and it's blocking nothing." I don't think we're on the same page about the definition of "blocking." When a thread blocks, that just means it stops executing temporarily. In java, this can be done with something like wait() or sleep(). Unless a thread of execution blocks, it will just continue to keep executing code. It can't just "wait" for user input and not be executing WITHOUT blocking. I haven't dealt with JButtons so I don't know how they work, but I do know that some Java utilities will automatically block and wait for a user's response for you.

Comment: Yes we are on the same page, and I know very well just what blocking means. Again, you're thinking in the mind set of creating a step-wise linear program. You don't need to worry about blocking, but rather *changing state*.

Comment: Ok, if we're on the same page about blocking, then please tell me how this is possible "it's doing nothing and it's blocking nothing." How can an application be running, be doing nothing, and not be blocking?

Comment: Just the same as the theoretic program I mentioned that has a single JButton. There is a GUI loop running at all times in the background that Swing manages.

Comment: I figured there was a background thread for the GUI. But when you actually make that JButton, the code that directly follows the line where you made the JButton is still executed right afterwards, isn't it?

Comment: @Tim: yes, but the then the program just sits, and the code that is added to the JButton's ActionListener doesn't do anything *until the user presses the JButton*. And here you can change how the program responds to the button press depending on *the state of the program* -- meaning the contents of the class's fields.

Comment: "yes, but the then the program just sits" So let me get this straight. You execute the line to create the JButton, then the line after that gets executed, but then the program just sits? It doesn't go on to execute the line after that?

Comment: @Tim: please see, run and study the code in **Edit 4** as a simple example of event-driven programming and to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: Ok. I think I'm kind of getting it then. I guess the thing I wasn't getting was that the GUI now will be the main "hub" that tells the ChessGame object (which is my main "hub" as of now, complete with game loop) what to do and when to do it. So the ChessGame object will have to be changed drastically. Where my ChessGame object as-of-now controls itself, the GUI will have to be the one controlling it instead. Without this, it didn't make sense to me because I would still have a game-loop running in the ChessGame object along with the gui (thus all the talk about blocking). Does this seem right?

Comment: @Tim: It's a worthwhile exercise, and one we all have to go through when changing from console to an event-driven programming paradigm. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at JDialog http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html. It can block within a Swing application without unnecessary complications.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta rethink your solution.  Think of standard in being already connected to your keyboard so there is something already writing to standard in.  Sorry there's no room at the standard inn.